# Transpose csv structure using python pandas

Tags: csv, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following csv structure:

```
'Country'    '1960'    '1961'    '1962'
AUS          450        567       723
NZ                      125       320
IND          350        375       395
SL        
PAK          100        115       218
```

Using Python Pandas how do I convert(transpose) the above structure to the following?

```
'Country'   'Year'   'Value'
AUS          1960     450
AUS          1961     567
AUS          1962     723
NZ           1960   
NZ           1961     125
...
```

My attempts at using pivot have been futile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:
year     1960  1961  1962
Country
AUS       450   567   723
NZ        NaN   125   320
IND       350   375   395
SL        NaN   NaN   NaN
PAK       100   115   218

In [20]: df.stack().reset_index()
Out[20]:
   Country  year    0
0      AUS  1960  450
1      AUS  1961  567
2      AUS  1962  723
3       NZ  1961  125
4       NZ  1962  320
5      IND  1960  350
6      IND  1961  375
7      IND  1962  395
8      PAK  1960  100
9      PAK  1961  115
10     PAK  1962  218
```

Apparently NaN are dropped along the way.

Comment: tried that. But I get this;                                                                                 ,level_0,level_1,0
0,0,Country,AUS
1,0,1960,450.0
2,0,1961,567.0
3,0,1962,723.0
4,1,Country,NZ
5,1,1961,125.0
6,1,1962,320.0
7,2,Country,IND
8,2,1960,350.0

Comment: Based on your answer, I tried df.transpose().stack().reset_index() and have come somewhere close to what I want

Comment: The output in my example, matches (except for NaN) exactly what you wanted to get. If you do not get the same result, this only means that you are extracting the data differently from the csv file, and your starting frame is different than mine.

Comment: Oh yes. I should have done this 'data.set_index('Country').stack().reset_index()' And I'll have to do a 'data.set_index('Country').stack(dropna=False).reset_index()' to include the nans. Thanks!!!!